# Java classes - best practice with constructors (android)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've built a class and would like to include a constructor which will construct the class from a cursor which will point to an SQLite DB.

I also have a database helper class which sits in the same package and has static variables which give labels to the columns in the cursor.

Should I use these references in the the constructor of the class or is that bad practice?

Thanks, 
m

here is a simple generic example asked for in the comments...

```
  public class carDbHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
      public static final int ROW_ID = 0;
      public static final int ROW_TYPE = 1;

      ...// all db helper code omitted

  }


 public class Car{
            private int id; 
            private String type; 

            public Car (Cursor c){
               this.id = c.getInt(carDbHelper.ROW_ID);
               this.id = c.getString(carDbHelper.TYPE_ID);
            }

        //Other code omitted
     }
```

Comment: Definitely not bad practice but personally I always try to avoid.

Comment: The reason I'm looking to do this is because I would like to sanitise the data that comes from the cursor. Particularly in the case of getInt(). This returns a 0 if the field is null where as I'd like it to return -1. Another option I have is to override the cursor methods to do some checking before it returns. Would you recommend this approach?

Comment: Yes I would override them too. It is most clean option IMO. see what others say but yes for these kind of things I normally override too and return what fits me better . It is clean and gives you more control.

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong with referencing static variables of some class from the constructor of the same or different class. Please post some code as that will help clarify.

Comment: Sorry I can't post the code because of confidentiality. I think I'll override the cursor class methods. Bit of a pain as there is a load of them to override!

Comment: You aught to be able to post some generic code that demonstrates your problem and does not conflict with the confidentiality. It will be helpful for future questions.

Comment: Yeah that's fair enough- will get some up there.

Comment: Not bad, could be better to use a factory pattern that can take a cursor and generate whatever class you need based on the cursor.

Comment: Do you have an example of such? Thanks. m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either copying object or referencing to object is good, the problem is that you need to control the object life time well.

I personally prefer copying object to referencing it, since it's really hard to know when object starts to exist or destroy if there're many continuous references on the same object.

Comment: In this case it is better to use references because the helper class probably has column names in `final static Strings`.